# Memory reset in Survival mode

Tags: memory, screeps

How to reset the `Memory` object every time I start new Survival game? It is saved between games which might be unconvenient to track current game state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Memory` object is saved because it can store not only your current Survival game state, but also another modes' data, including World mode in the future. `Memory` is linked to your account, not to a single game.

In order to track game data better to use [`Room.memory`](https://screeps.com/docs/Room.php#memory) object rather than global `Memory`. Or you can reset your global `Memory` on the first tick in survival mode room using [`Room.survivalInfo.score`](https://screeps.com/docs/Room.php#survivalInfo):

```
var room = Game.spawns.Spawn1.room;
if(room.survivalInfo.score == 0) {
  // reset Memory here
}
```